# Is there a geo lookup function for kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a way in kql to convert a public IP address to a country?
Basically I'm looking for the equivalent to Splunks iplocation function from SPL.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update: a new function in KQL: **geo_info_from_ip_address()**.

This function allows you to retrieve geolocation information about IPv4 or IPv6 addresses, such as country, state, city, and coordinates. This can help you enrich your data analysis with geographic context, such as identifying the origin of network traffic, the location of users or devices, or the distribution of events across regions. The function uses GeoLite2 data created by MaxMind, a leading provider of IP intelligence and online fraud prevention tools.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/geo-info-from-ip-address-function

Answer (score -1):

Kusto is a platform and does not hold its own dataset for ip->geo mapping.
Given you bring your own dataset - you can use ipv4/ipv6 functions to build such lookup.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalarfunctions#ipv4ipv6-functions